# TradingView resolveSymbol method called twice

Tags: vue.js, charts, tradingview-api

I'm trying to integrate TradingView library with my web app. The chart is loading fine, but when loading both, resolveSymbol method is called twice.

```
Datafeed.Container.prototype.resolveSymbol = function (
    symbolName,
    onSymbolResolvedCallback,
    onResolveErrorCallback
  ) {
    this._send(
      datafeedUrl + this._symbolResolveURL,
      {
        symbol: symbolName ,
      },
      function (dataObj) {
          onSymbolResolvedCallback(dataObj);
      }
    );
  };
```

Actually the data returned on both times are the same. The Chrome dev tools network tab shows the calls as below

[image]

What is that going wrong? Somehow the library assumes the symbol is not resolved. How to rectify that?